# How to move to multiple view controllers?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift

I want to programmatically move from a viewController to another using Apple's new Swift language.  I've googled and read through the docs, and I see how to use a single ViewController.  Does anyone have an example or documentation on how to switch between View Controllers?

Comment: Could you provide some code that you have tried? :) Thank you!

Comment: I haven't tried much yet.  I added a second view controller in AppDelegate like this:  var itemsViewController: BNRItemsViewController = BNRItemsViewController() but I wasn't sure how to actually push it on top of the view controller stack.  I'm trying the "presentViewController" now, but  that only works if you're in a UIViewController subclassed object.

Comment: Isn't it the same way you've always done it?

Comment: I'm kind of new to objective C, but no?  Usually in my AppDelegate.m, I load my default view controller (that seems to happen magically in Swift?) and then from there, I can load different view controllers.  I guess for now I'll use a story board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this detailed in the class documentation for `UIViewController`.

**Example 1**
Here is an example of using the `-presentViewConroller:` method (assuming this code is written in a `UIViewController` subclass):

```
var secondViewController = UIViewController() //create your second view controller. 
self.presentViewController(secondViewController, true, NULL)
```

---

**Example 2**
This is how you would present the second `UIViewController` via storyboards (again assuming this code is written in a `UIViewController` subclass):

```
self.preformSegueWithIdentifier("segueIdentfier", self);
```

---

Comment: So is the accepted method (I realize the language is ultra new) to use the ViewController.swift file as the "default" view controller, and then load other view controllers through there, as things happen?

Comment: This is how you would do it programmatically, though I would imaging that using storyboards will be more common.

Comment: I guess a better question then is if I create an empty application, I don't have a storyboard, or a ViewController.  If I create a UIViewController class, what is the magic to get it loaded in the AppDelegate?

Comment: shouldn't be `nil` instead of `NULL`? I'm new to swift and iOS programming in general, but I've found always the first one in examples...